Were ancient Greece tridents different designs from other historical examples?
For a tattoo, I'm researching the trident as a spearfishing tool and a weapon. The one I'd like to depict should be one from ancient Greece, preferably around 400 BC (the time when Plato lived).
Looking at the Wikipedia page, it appears as though the shape varies considerably based on culture, time, place, and, I'm guessing, purpose as well.
Google Image is less than helpful because it brings up so many cheap, industrially produced statues where I wouldn't trust in their historicity. Looking at photos taken in museums, the statues (of e.g. Poseidon) that would have been holding a trident, usually don't have one anymore. Ostensibly because it wouldn't have been stone, but metal.
Is there a depiction of a trident where it is safe to say that such a one would have actually existed in the Greece of around 400 BC?

Varied
Looking at some examples, it appears the Ancient Greeks had multiple representations.
It does seem that the tines were generally the same length.
The following are all dated circa 550 BC - 360 BC in Greek art, so broadly what you are looking for.
From Wikipedia:



I'd look at Greek art other than statuary. My examples were a plaque, coin, and red-figure vase -- none of those have metal tridents that can rust away!

This is exactly what I was looking but didn't have the right approach to search for. Thank you!!

While artistic depictions on stone and ceramic are more likely to survive to our day,  there are also a scant few archeological finds of actual tridents from the 4th century BCE. Here is one such example (the article linking to a Turkish language original article), showing the distinct Greek trident shape:

Coins such as this one (450-425 BCE) or this one (400-375 BCE) are another good source of depictions and confirm the squared-off shape with inward-facing barbs:

